# GWT RequestFactory not firing properly after using edit()

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

I have a problem using "fire()" with a GWT RequestFactory after I've used it to unfreeze and edit a proxy.

If I have two request factory objects and their associated contexts like this:

```
private SyntheticRequest req1 = requestFactory.someRequest(); 
private Request<xProxy> sendRequest1 = req1.something(); 

private SyntheticRequest req2 = requestFactory.someRequest(); 
private Request<xProxy> sendRequest2 = req2.something();
```

using "fire()" on the first request works fine:

```
sendRequest1.fire(new Receiver<xProxy>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(xProxy response) {
        ...
        if (somethingIsTrue){
               xProxy x = req2.edit(response);  //<-- **I think this causes a problem later, although the proxy "x" works as expected here.**
               x.setSomething("something"); 
               update();                
         }
});
```

that part runs ok because I get to the "onSuccess".  But when this one runs "update()", which looks like this:

```
private void update(){
  sendRequest2.fire(new Receiver<xProxy>(){
       ...onFailure...
       ...onSuccess...
  });
}
```

sendRequest2 always fails, with the error

> Server Error Index:0 Size:0

and I put a breakpoint in the code for the "something()" service and it never even gets to that code! There must be something about the "req2.edit()" that hurts req2 and sendRequest2, but what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is 'b'? the line  `xProxy x = req2.edit(b);`  is the first time it's mentioned? is it supposed to be  `xProxy x = req2.edit(response);`

Anyway.. that is not the problem.. 
'Server Error' indicates that RequestFactory caught an exception during the processing of a request, server-side. Something (but maybe not something()) is throwing an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

If you have a look at RequestFactoryServlet.java (which you can replace with your own very easily btw) you can see it setting up a try catch block that catches all exceptions when processing a request. It passes them to 'DefaultExceptionHandler' which wraps them in a ServerFailure, and that gets returned to you GWT code as an onFailure() call.

An easy way to find where the exception is being thrown is set a breakpoint on IndexOutOfBoundsException, making sure to catch 'caught' exceptions as well as uncaught.

Comment: I've corrected the reference to "b" aidanok, you are correct, it should have been "response".  Thanks, I will try the breakpoint that you suggest.  I suspect something happens to req2 when I do the req2.edit(response), but we'll see, and I'll report back.

Comment: Its not a problem to edit a response proxy in a new, or yet to be fired context, this would be normal flow. 'Server Error: xxx' always indicates a server-side exception has been caught.

Comment: Thanks!  There was an indexing problem. Since req2 was the edited unfrozen proxy, when the context was fire()'d, it was also going through all the other setters of the proxy, even ones I didn't touch, who knows why.  One of the setters had a problem which showed up during the fire(). Any ideas why the other setters were getting used in the proxy? (Setters other than the "setSomething()" in my example).

Comment: If getId() or getVersion() are returning null for the returned proxy, requestfactory will treat it as un-persisted, and send the whole object, rather than just the changes. Also for ValueProxy objects, it will always send the whole object, not just the changes. (I'm guessing its an EntityProxy though, since you are calling update().. )

Comment: Thanks aidanok.  My proxy does extend ValueProxy (but only because the wizard gave it to me, not from some choice of mine).  I do have a getId method, but not getVersion.  I don't understand these nuances well enough, can you point me to a good place to better understand?

Comment: http://tbroyer.posterous.com/gwt-211-requestfactory - is a good intro, and there are other posts on mr. broyers  blog too.. There aren't a lot of 'complete' examples on RF, because its not an end-to-end solution. The server-side is very much left up to the dev to decide what to do in terms of persistence and mapping of domain objects. The dev guide/google are your friends I guess!